# Construction of secure Elliptic Curve subgroup over a much larger field

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

How can we construct an Elliptic Curve subgroup of cryptographic interest out of an Elliptic Curve over a much larger finite field, including the familiar $\Bbb F_p$ for prime $p$? The Discrete Logarithm Problem and related should conjecturally require $\mathcal O(\sqrt q)$ field operations, where $q$ is the subgroup's order, which must be known.

---

Motivation: in a signature à la Schnorr, having an analog to [Schnorr (sub)groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group), but with resistance to NFS and index calculus regardless of choice of $p$; yet still with  parameter $p$ to slightly tune up the cost of field operations, for likely increased security against ASICs and hypothetical quantum computers usable for cryptanalysis, at a given group/signature size.

One way to fulfill that need would be a randomized generation procedure parametrized by bit sizes for $p$ and $q$ (much larger for $p$), yielding primes $p$ and $q$ and the equation of an Elliptic Curve group over field $\Bbb F_p$ having order a multiple of $q$, with some presumption of hardness of the DLP.

I care much more for security for a given size of $q$, and simplicity of implementation on the signature verifier side (where side channels are a non-issue), than on speed, and on ease of making a secure (side-channel resistant) implementation on the side with the private key.

I envision a 192 to 512-bit $q$ for 96 to 256-bit conjectured security (counted in field operations in $\Bbb F_p$), and $p$ several times that size (at least twice).

Comment: Why do you need NFS / index calculus resistance? Unless you're using pairings they don't seem to be relevant. Regardless a pairing-friendly curve seems to be the best approach, since it will allow you to work with $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ instead of $E(\mathbb{F}_{p^k})$ all the time.

Comment: @Conrado  I tried to clarify. I make mention of NFS and index calculus as the reason I want an EC (sub)group, rather than just use a Schnorr (sub)group: as far as I know these algorithms are a consideration for parametrization of the later type of (sub)group only, at least for my main application (now explicit): signature à la Schnorr.

Comment: Is there anything I'm missing here that stops you from picking a curve s.t. $q$ is a factor of the big-curve's order?

Comment: @SEJPM: no, you are not missing anything. A curve of order $n$ about $p$ on the field $\Bbb F_p$, with $q$ a prime factor of $n$, would be just what I want, provided there is a feasible process to generate that with some control on the size of $q$ and $p$, and some presumption of security.

Answer (score 4):

[Hasse's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse's_theorem_on_elliptic_curves) notes that for an elliptic curve over a finite field with $\mathcal{Q}$ elements (which would mean $\mathcal{Q}=p$ for a prime field $\mathbb{F}_p$) that has $N$ points, the following holds:

$|N-(\mathcal{Q}+1)|\le 2 \sqrt{\mathcal{Q}}$

For the sake of illustration, let's take $\mathcal{Q}=p=8191$. This gives us $|N-(8191+1)| \le 2\sqrt{8191}$, leading to this range of possible numbers of points (rounded): $8011 \le N \le 8373$. Since this gives a hard lower and upper bound on the number of points, clearly, a prime-order curve over a large field with the constraint that the order of the curve $q$ is significantly smaller than the field prime $p$ isn't possible.

Thus you need to ignore prime-order curves and instead have a large group $\ell$ and a significantly smaller prime subgroup given by cofactor $h$ on which we operate. The [worst case impact of a large cofactor](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/twist.html) is limited to a speedup of *a factor* of $\sqrt{h}$ compared to the standard Pollard $\rho$ attack—but that focuses on the large group $\ell$, not the cofactor itself. With $\ell$ being the “cofactor” and the real main group being what normally is considered a cofactor, things seem to get hairy and unclear in their actual impact.

Even if this is an acceptable risk, [Igor E. Shparlinksi and Andrew V. Sutherland, Finding Elliptic Curves With a Subgroup of Prescribed Size, 2017](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.7887.pdf) gives you a very dense outline of what an algorithm could look like to find curves with a cofactor in a pre-determined range. Even then, the runtime of the algorithm is painfully slow for sufficiently large $p$ for $\mathbb{F}_p$ (assuming you're in the 2048-bit range for $p$), namely $mp^{1/2+o(1)}$ to the point that it is likely impractical.

Comment: This reference is spot-on, if a bit on the theoretical side for a mere engineer like me. Thanks a lot for pointing that! There is a slightly updated journal paper online and open-access: Igor E. Shparlinski and Andrew V. Sutherland, [_Finding elliptic curves with a subgroup of prescribed size_](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdfplus/10.1142/S1793042117500099), in [International Journal of Number Theory, 2017](https://doi.org/10.1142/S1793042117500099).

Comment: @fgrieu Good find! And yeah, there's probably a chance to have a paper consisting of just someone sitting down, digesting the whole thing and making pseudocode for actually doing it.

Comment: @xorhash I don't see why a prime-order curve over a large field isn't possible. Won't there be around [$2\sqrt(\mathcal{Q})/\log{\mathcal{Q}}$ primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/288786/541412) in that Hasse bound?

Comment: @Conrado My bad, OP's question wants $q$ to be much lower than $p$, so you can find *a* prime-order curve over a large field, but you won't find a prime-order curve with an order significantly smaller than the field prime. Clarifying.